# Input current to a non-isolated boost converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I am measuring the current at the input to a non isolated boost converter.

See Fig 1

[image: Fig 1]

I am measuring different currents on the positive input and the negative input terminals to the boost converter.

I am not sure why this is the case.

Here are some examples of the input currents measured:

Measurement 1

- +ve side input current: 5.045 A
- -ve side input current: 3.359 A

Measurement 2

- +ve side input current: 10.090 A
- -ve side input current: 7.929 A

DC current measurements in both cases. Measured with 2 x shunts. Shunt 1 connected between the DC input source positive and the positive input of the boost converter, shunt 2 connected between DC input source negative and the negative input of the boost converter.

The boost converter in this case regulates the input current.

The power supply connected to the boost converter input is floating from earth ground. The output side of the boost converter is also floating from earth ground.

I am trying to understand these results.

Why is the negative side input current measured lower than the positive input side current?

Can you suggests some tests I could carry out to understand this better if necessary?

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram and indicate exactly how you are taking the two measurements.

Comment: In addition to what Chris says, please add whether you are measuring AC or DC current.

Comment: DC Current measurements in both cases . Measured with 2 x shunts . Shunt 1 connected between the DC input source positive and the positive input of the boost converter , Shunt 2 connected between DC input source negative and the negative input of the boost converter .

Comment: You can edit your own question, you don't have to add comments. Also please double check the four bullets, there are either duplicates or it is unclear what you mean.

Comment: In addition to Rohat and Chris: Please tell us what meter you are using, is it RMS, simple digital or an analog meter? What is the load? Perhaps a picture of your test setup?

Comment: Do you have anything else connected to the negative side? E.g. is there a metal case connected to it?

Comment: No,there is no metal case connected to the negative side

Comment: I updated post to add diagram showing the setup , the measurement made and how the measurements are being made .

Comment: Is it the same shunt, or are it two separate ones? Power resistors can have a substantial tolerance / deviation from the printed value. Disconnect them and measure their value. Did you try to flip the two shunts and see if the differens flips too? Same goes with the DVM, if you have two DVM's try exchanging them.

Comment: Two separate shunts . Same mV /A rating

Comment: Current shunts are used for the measurements ( not resistors)   1mv/A  . Shunts were verified by connecting them in series and the same current was measured by both shunts .

Comment: Can you add a picture of the setup and its direct surroundings?

Comment: Shunt value not what you think it is? One multimeter low on battery?

Comment: I guess the current must be finding another path  in parallel to the shunt back to input  DC source -Ve  somehow . Measurements made x 2x Agilent 34401A DVM's sensing shunt voltages .

Comment: What you've drawn is not possible, so some aspect is not as believed.  Current is flowing via an additional ground path, or the shunts are not the same, or the meter is not suited to the time domain variation of the current waveform, or the two measuremts are made under different combinations.

Comment: Did you swap the meters?

Comment: Chris . I think this must be the case . I need to carry out more tests to confirm there are no parallel paths .

Comment: Jippie . Yes . It is not the meters. Also verified the shunts and meters by connecting 2x shunts in series and confirming 2x meters measured the same current .

Comment: Did you check the wave forms with a scope? Mind the scope ground reference.

Comment: A large RC filter is needed to average the RMS current into a voltage.  Your DMM is not a true RMS voltmeter and you have noise + ripple.